# Backdrop color behind background Android app

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout

Having trouble identifying what this is actually called. In most apps you see this portion blend with the color of the toolbar. Which is what I would like to do in this case. (The area in question is the blueish segment above the toolbar)

[image: The area in question in the blueish segment above the toolbar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called a status bar (the blue thing)